# Where is $G64\uparrow \uparrow G64$ in the Fast-growing hierarchy?

Tags: big-numbers

I am trying to find out how $G64\uparrow \uparrow G64$ can be represented by the Fast-growing hierarchy, but I do not know how this can be done.

Is there a way to simply convert between those two notations?

Comment: An upper bound is , if $G=G64$ denotes Graham's number, $3 \uparrow^{G_n+1} 3$ which is slightly larger than $G_{65}$ , hence the level is still $f_{\omega+1}$ , as Graham's number. In fact, this number is not "much larger than" $G$ in googology-standards. Maybe , someone else can prove that it is vastly smaller than $G_{65}$.

Comment: Hi @Peter
I am not sure I understand why G64 ↑↑ G64 should be smaller than G65. Would you please explain in more detail why this would be the case?

Comment: This is due to Saibian who explained that teration (taking $N\uparrow \uparrow N$) has virtually no effect , if $N$ is way beyond the tetrational level. This is of course not a proof , but he proved a theorem that might help to upper-bound this expression , but I am not an expert in such (usually difficult) manipulations. Maybe , it helps if you read his site about large numbers. Just google "large number site"

Answer (score 1):

By the [Knuth Arrow Theorem](https://googology.fandom.com/wiki/Knuth_Arrow_Theorem) (KAT) we have,
for any integers $x \ge 2, a \ge 2, b \ge 1, c \ge 1,$
$$(a \uparrow ^x b) \uparrow ^xc < a \uparrow ^x(b+c).$$

Thus, with $G=G_{64},$ we have

$G_{65}\\
=3\uparrow^G3\\
=3\uparrow^{G-1}(3\uparrow^{G-1}3)\\
\gt (3\uparrow^{G-1}3)\uparrow^{G-1}(3\uparrow^{G-1}3-3)\quad \text{by KAT}\\
\gg G\uparrow^{G-1}G\\
\gg G\uparrow^2 G
$

Therefore, $G\uparrow^2 G$ is still at level $f_{\omega+1}$ in the FGH, because $G_{65}\lt f_{\omega+1}(65)$. (It can be shown by induction that $G_{k}\lt f_{\omega+1}(k)$ for all $k\ge 6.$)